# Zend debugger in eclipse - timeout every time

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-debugger

I am running a virtual server in the US.

I am trying to get my eclipse machine at home (outside the USA), to connect to the USA server.

I have setup Zend on the server.  When I run phpinfo() I get the following zend output.  Note: **1.2.3.4** will be the external WAN IP address of my ADSL router at home.

```
Directive                    Local Value         Master Value
zend_debugger.allow_hosts    127.0.0.1,1.2.3.4 127.0.0.1,1.2.3.4
zend_debugger.allow_tunnel    no value          no value
zend_debugger.deny_hosts    no value          no value
zend_debugger.expose_remotely  always          always
zend_debugger.httpd_uid    -1                  -1
zend_debugger.max_msg_size    2097152          2097152
zend_debugger.tunnel_max_port  65535          65535
zend_debugger.tunnel_min_port  1024                  1024
```

So zend looks like it is working ok on the server side.

When I run a debug session and select 'Test Debugger' I get a timeout every time.  I have already added **dummy.php** to the root folder of the server.

In 'installed debuggers' I double clicked on Zend and have put my external WAN IP address.  I noticed that the port is 10000, I also have webmin running on this port on the server, will there be a conflict?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, and I read the apache error.log file. there was written the problem. What is in your error.log file?